# Question about an estimate

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $P$ be a propability measure, $T_n$ a sequence of estimators for some quantity. I try to understand how this inequality works:

$$P(||T_n(X) - \tau|| >  \varepsilon) \leq P(||T_n(X) - \tau_n|| > \varepsilon/2) + P(||\tau_n - \tau|| > \varepsilon/2).
$$

It is obvious that $$\varepsilon < ||T_n(X) - \tau|| = ||T_n(X) - \tau_n + \tau_n - \tau|| \leq ||T_n(X) - \tau_n ||+||\tau_n - \tau||  .$$

But I dont see, how this allows me to make the estimate above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by contradiction that if $\|T_n(X)-\tau\| >\epsilon$ then either $\|T_n(X)-\tau_n\| >\epsilon /2$ or $\|\tau_n-\tau\| >\epsilon/2$. Then use the fact that $A \subseteq B \cup C$ implies $P(A) \leq P(B \cup C) \leq P(B)+P(C)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can split up $P(||T_n(X)-\tau_n||>\varepsilon)$ using the law of total probability as 
 (using $A_n=||T_n(X)-\tau_n||, B_n=||\tau_n-\tau||$) $$P(A_n>\varepsilon)=P(A_n>\varepsilon|B_n\le \varepsilon/2)P(B_n\le \varepsilon/2)\\ +P(A_n>\varepsilon| B_n>\varepsilon/2)P(B_n>\varepsilon/2) \tag{*}$$

Then note that from the triangle inequality, as you have noted,

$$\varepsilon < ||T_n(X)-\tau||\le A_n+B_n  \\ \text{gives that the event } \{B_n \le \varepsilon/2\} \implies \text{the event }\{A_n > \varepsilon/2\}$$ $$\implies P(B_n\le \varepsilon/2) \le P(A_n > \varepsilon/2) \tag{1}$$ and having $$P(A_n>\varepsilon|B_n\le \varepsilon/2)\le 1 \tag{2}$$ we can multiply $(1),(2)$ to get the first product in $(*)$ bounded above by $P(A_n > \varepsilon/2)$ and multiplying $P(B_n>\varepsilon/2)$ to both sides of $$P(A_n>\varepsilon|B_n\le \varepsilon/2)\le 1$$ gives the second product in $(*)$ to be bounded above by $P(B_n>\varepsilon/2)$.